# Calculate the GPS position in 2D inside a camera image depending of FOV

Tags: math, gps, augmented-reality

I have a camera with a known FOV that is located to a known GPS coord with a known orientation.

I have another GPS coord and would like to display a dot on the camera image (augmented reality) of this GPS coord.

Is it possible to do that with the info?

PS: The distance between the 2 GPS coord is less than a few kilometers so perhaps we can do some approximation

Answer (score 0):

You would need to track the orientation of the camera.  GPS can track the position and velocity of the receiver, but most setups cannot tell you anything about the orientation.  So, without additional information, the answer is "no".

If you have 3-axis magnetic and inertial sensors (accelerometer and rate gyros) on the camera, you may be able to compute an orientation based on gravity and geomagnetic field -- although the magnetic component would be sensitive to local magnetic distortions.

If you ask the user to wave the camera around, you may be able to combine inertial sensors with GPS velocity readings to determine your orientation -- although I'm not sure the data would be good enough for a stable orientation.  Using computer vision techniques on the live-view images might help to stabilize this kind of tracking, though.

In any case, you'll want to look up [Kalman filtering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter), which is the technique used to do this kind of tracking.

Comment: Thanks, in fact, i know the orientation, i have in the system a gyro, a mag and an accelerometer sensors. The question was more, how to compute it :)

Comment: That depends on how your orientation is represented.  You will need to choose a local cartesian coordinate system, and compute the [camera matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_matrix) based on the orientation (as converted to your chosen coords).  Then, use the camera matrix to compute the screen position of vector between your current and target positions.